# need help on writing compound statements in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write compound statements in if condition -mysql ?

It is returning an error for me like:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE n INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;
   DECL' at line 40
```

Sombody please help

Here is the query I am using

```
...........................................
   IF(tarif='LT')
   THEN

   CREATE TABLE costSlabs SELECT `Start`,`End`,Cost FROM energy_slabs where SiteId=NEW.SiteID and `Start` < totalUnits;
   DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE newStart INT;
   DECLARE newEnd INT;
   DECLARE newCost DOUBLE;
   DECLARE finalCost DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM costSlabs INTO n;
   SET i=0;
   WHILE i<n DO 
    SELECT `Start`, `End`,Cost INTO newStart,newEnd,newCost FROM costSlabs LIMIT i,1 ;

 IF(newEnd<totalUnits)
 THEN 
 SET finalCost = finalCost + ((newEnd-newStart) * newCost);

 ELSE
...........................................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IF` statement is valid within the context of a MySQL stored program (stored procedure, function or trigger). Outside of the context of a MySQL stored program, it isn't a valid SQL statement.

We're not seeing the context of these statements, but based on the reference to **`NEW.`** in the SQL SELECT, without any table or table alias named `NEW`, I'll assume that this SQL is in the context of a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

I suspect that the problem you are encountering is due to the semicolon delimiter, which effectively ends the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. In order to create a trigger that includes semicolon characters, it's necessary to specify a different statement delimiter. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytrig
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.col1 = 'foo';
   SET NEW.col2 = 'bar';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The first statement specifies that `$$` will be used as the delimiter to end a statement. With that set, the statements following will be read together as a single statement, until a `$$` delimiter is encountered. That will end the statement, and allow it be executed. This basically prevents the semicolons within the trigger body from prematurely "ending" the statement.

Once the statements are completed, you can change the delimiter back to a semicolon.

The block of SQL text posted in the question is invalid on its own. I suspect that the syntax error is being returned from the execution of a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, but that's just a guess, since there's not enough context in the question to make a conclusion.

Also, I believe that within a MySQL stored program (such as a TRIGGER), all of the `DECLARE` statements must appear *before* other statements, such as `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried like this but now it shows an error
[Err] 1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger. any idea ..?

Comment: A DDL statement like `CREATE TABLE` statement causes an implicit commit; and this isn't allowed in the context of a trigger. There's some other significant problems in the design of your trigger: looping through the a series of `SELECT ... LIMIT i,1` is inefficient, there's no order by clause, so the rows that are goign to be returned is not deterministic (each execution of that SELECT statement can return the exact same row every time, and be within spec); that whole mess should be replaced with a cursor loop. There's a reference to `totalUnits`, but that's not declared anywhere.

Comment: We can't tell what this trigger is supposed to be doing, what the end result is supposed to be. Whatever that is, this trigger is doing it wrong.